# data not being displayed when I go to another state ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hello guys I'm facing a problem. I'm saving some data in `$scope.somevariable` and then I'm going to another state. The problem that I'm facing is that when I go to another state I do not see the data rather I'm seeing the view I'm trying to render which is

```
<ion-view view-title="ShowUserList">
  <ion-content>
    <!-- <ion-checkbox ng-model='checkStatus1' ng-click="showAlert(checkStatus1)">
        <h2 class="ng-binding">{{tittle}}</h2>
        <span class="distance ng-binding"></span>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Created : {{created}}</h3>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Target : {{targetD}}</h3>
    </ion-checkbox>  -->

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item  collection-repeat="user in users">
        Hello, {{user}}!
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the controller from where I'm trying to render

```
.controller('optionActionCtrl' , function($scope, $timeout , $http , $ionicModal , $state){
    // Triggered in the login modal to close it


  $scope.closeActionModal = function() {
    console.log('hello');
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.openAddActionModel = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
    // $('#action_datePicker').val(new Date());
  };

  $scope.showListOfUser = function(){
    //call made to the server

    // add all the users 
    $scope.users = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'];

    $state.go('app.UserListForAssigned')
  };
})
```

and here is the state where I'm trying to go

```
.state('app.UserListForAssigned', {
      url: '/userList',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/showUsers.html',
          controller: 'optionActionCtrl'
        },
      }
    })
```

**Previous state**

```
 .state('app.options', {
      url: '/options',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/options.html',
          controller: 'optionActionCtrl'
        },
      }
    })
```

Comment: Can you add the first state on your post ?

Comment: @Habkamas I have added the previous state

Comment: You would like to pass the entire list of users or just 1 selected user?

Answer (score 1):

This method works if you want to pass either the entire list of users or just 1 selected user.

I will assume that in your previous state, you click on a button to call for `showListOfUser`. You can adjust accordingly afterwards.

**Previous state:**

app

```
   .state('app.options', {
          url: '/options',
          views: {
            'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/options.html',
              controller: 'optionActionCtrl'
            },
          }
        })
```

controller

```
.controller('optionActionCtrl' , function($scope, $timeout , $http , $ionicModal , $state){
    // Triggered in the login modal to close it


  $scope.closeActionModal = function() {
    console.log('hello');
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.openAddActionModel = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
    // $('#action_datePicker').val(new Date());
  };

  $scope.showListOfUser = function(){
    //call made to the server

    // add all the users 
    $scope.users = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'];
  };
})
```

Html

```
  <a class="button" ng-click="showListOfUser()" ng-href="#/userList/{{users}}">click</a>
```

**New state:**

app

```
.state('app.UserListForAssigned', {
      url: '/userList/:userID',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/showUsers.html',
          controller: 'UserListCtrl'
        },
      }
    })
```

controller (create a separate controller)

```
.controller('UserListCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    console.log('userID: ' + $stateParams.userID);

    $scope.users = $stateparams.userID;

});
```

Instead of using `$state.go()`, I am passing `$scope.users` through `ng-href` and retrieving it through `$stateParams`. Under `.state('app.UserListForAssigned', ...)`, `url` must be defined to take in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to move `$scope.users = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'];` outside of `showListOfUser` function.

You are using this function to set `$scope.users` with some values and to move to the other `state`. Then, on the other `state`, I think that `showListOfUser` function is no longer used, so `$scope.users` doesn't exist.

Comment: Isn't there any way that I fill the users array in the function because I don't need it until that function is called. right now I'm just assuming that when I move to another state the scope variable is emptied or something happens. I need to retain the data that is being set in that function because I need it in the view which is being rendered when that states get called. 

I found a way and that was to call a function in ng-init but from what I have read on various forums it's not a good practice to use it

Comment: Hum I think you could use either a new controller especially for app.UserListForAssigned, or create a condition that retains data only if current state if app.UserListForAssigned. 

I found this, but I did not test it : $state.is('your_stat') return true is current state is 'your_state'.